# NMAP - create delay between scanning multiple IP addresses

Tags: nmap, port-scanning

I'm wondering whether or not it is possible to create a delay after scanning say 4 IP addresses.

```
--scan-delay 500000
```

I understand the delay function however am quite unsure if you can stagnate the scan in this way. Thank you in advance for the help, I'm aware this isn't much of a contribution however I'm struggling to find the relevant aid within the nmap documentation and am unsure where to find help for this!

Answer (score 0):

`--scan-delay` introduces a delay between each probe that is sent. Your example would result in an incredibly slow scan. If you want to delay between groups of targets, run separate Nmap commands and use a `sleep` between each command.